# Is there any possible issue of using Solr 8.7 in cloud mode on Zookeeper 3.4.5

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am implementing Solr 8.7 in cloud mode with existing zookeeper 3.4.5.

Is there any possible issue?

Couldn't find any compatibility matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know Solr 8.7 still uses Zookeeper 3.5.x, which [should be backwards compatible with 3.4.x according to the Zookeeper project](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/ReleaseManagement).

Comment: Well, solr 8.7 integrates zk 3.6.2. Thats what i am worried about.

Comment: Ah, thanks for checking. I based my assumption on nothing being mentioned in the release logs except for Solr 8.2 where the upgrade to 3.5 happened. Zookeeper doesn't say anything other than "ZooKeeper 3.6.0 clients are compatible with 3.5 servers as long as you are not using new APIs not present in 3.5.", so .. you might want to just try it (or upgrade to a more recent ZK version, of course).

Comment: Upgrade is not an option. ZK is already implemented, and not in my hands. I just want to make sure that Solr 8.7 will work. Tried, the Solr mail list. But no reply.

Comment: To note,  tried to run in local. It seems to be running. But, can not test all fail scenarios.